# Two objects separated by a distance, with different speeds, how much seconds does the second need to reach the first one‽

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Tortoise racing](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55e2adece53b4cdcb900006c). The statement is:

```
Two tortoises named A and B must run a race. A starts with an average speed of 720 feet per hour. Young B knows she runs faster than A, and furthermore has not finished her cabbage.

When she starts, at last, she can see that A has a 70 feet lead but B's speed is 850 feet per hour. How long will it take B to catch A?

More generally: given two speeds v1 (A's speed, integer > 0) and v2 (B's speed, integer > 0) and a lead g (integer > 0) how long will it take B to catch A?

The result will be an array [hour, min, sec] which is the time needed in hours, minutes and seconds (round down to the nearest second) or a string in some languages.

If v1 >= v2 then return nil, nothing, null, None or {-1, -1, -1} for C++, C, Go, Nim, [] for Kotlin or "-1 -1 -1".
Examples:

(form of the result depends on the language)

race(720, 850, 70) => [0, 32, 18] or "0 32 18"
race(80, 91, 37)   => [3, 21, 49] or "3 21 49"

** Note:

    See other examples in "Your test cases".

    In Fortran - as in any other language - the returned string is not permitted to contain any redundant trailing whitespace: you can use dynamically allocated character strings.

** Hints for people who don't know how to convert to hours, minutes, seconds:

    Tortoises don't care about fractions of seconds

    Think of calculation by hand using only integers (in your code use or simulate integer division)

    or Google: "convert decimal time to hours minutes seconds"
```

To find a solution by miself I have thought the following:

1. How much time does it take for the second tortoise to travel the initial distance which separates it to the first one (g)?

We do a rule by 3:

```
850 feets -> 3600 s 
70 feets -> x s
x = 3600s * 70 feets / 850 feets 
x = 296,47s
```

2. How much distance does the first tortoise runs in the previous time (x)?

We apply the rule by 3:

```
3600 s -> 720 feets
296,47 s -> x feets
x = 720 feets * 296,47 s / 3600 s
x = 59,294s
```

And we repeat 1. and 2. untils distance is very small, near 0.

I have written the following answer in code:

```
public class Tortoise {
  static final double HOURS_TO_SECONDS = 3600;
  static final double MINUTES_TO_SECONDS = 60;
  static final String DECIMAL_ENDS_WITH999 = ".*\\.[9]{3,}.*";   

  public static int[] race/**/(int v1, int v2, double distanceTraveledByTortoise1) {
    if(v1 >= v2) return null;
    double secondsTortoise2TravelsDistance = 0, totalSeconds = 0;

    while(Math.abs(distanceTraveledByTortoise1) > 1e-6){
      secondsTortoise2TravelsDistance = HOURS_TO_SECONDS*distanceTraveledByTortoise1/v2; 
      totalSeconds += secondsTortoise2TravelsDistance;
      distanceTraveledByTortoise1 = v1*secondsTortoise2TravelsDistance/HOURS_TO_SECONDS;
    }
    double hours = totalSeconds / HOURS_TO_SECONDS;
    if(String.valueOf(hours).matches(DECIMAL_ENDS_WITH999)){
      hours++;
    }
    double minutes = (totalSeconds % HOURS_TO_SECONDS) / MINUTES_TO_SECONDS;
    if(String.valueOf(minutes).matches(DECIMAL_ENDS_WITH999)){
      minutes = ++minutes % MINUTES_TO_SECONDS;
    }
    double seconds = (totalSeconds % MINUTES_TO_SECONDS);
    if(String.valueOf(seconds).matches(DECIMAL_ENDS_WITH999)){
      seconds = ++seconds % MINUTES_TO_SECONDS;
    }
    return new int[]{(int)hours,(int)minutes,(int)seconds};
  }
}
```

I would like to know and understand what mathematical reasoning leads us to the following formula to calculate directly totalSeconds‽:

```
totalSecondsTaken = (g*3600) / (v2-v1) ;
```

Which is being used in the answer marked as best practices, [here is the link.](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/55e2b8078f2264bb8e00006c/groups/5614b0cb2283aa778b0000c7)

I have also read:

- [Giving the speed, find meeting points of two objects.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103022/giving-the-speed-find-meeting-points-of-two-objects)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118922/convert-seconds-value-to-hours-minutes-seconds
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766318/converting-double-to-string

Comment: Due to some unfortunate wording, this problem can’t really be solved as stated: you only know `A`’s _average_ speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v_2>v_1$, then the distance between the tortoises whill shrink at a steady pace. What pace is that? It might be easiest to think one hour ahead and see what happens during that hour.

In one hour, tortoise A has walked $v_1$ feet, while tortoise B has walked $v_2$ feet. Thus the gap has shrunk by $v_2 - v_1$ feet in this one hour. Which means that the speed at which the gap shrinks is $v_2-v_1$ feet per hour. If the gap is $g$ feet to start with, and it shrinks at a speed of $v_2-v_1$ feet per hour, it will take $\frac{g}{v_2-v_1}$ hours for it to get to $0$.

Finally, we have the number of hours, but we want the number of seconds. There are $3600$ seconds to an hour, so if it takes $\frac{g}{v_2-v_1}$ hours, it will take $\frac{3600\cdot g}{v_2-v_1}$ seconds.